# How to throttle a forkJoin Angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

In my component I am grouping together a set of operations that need to be carried out. The order that they are carried out is not important but I want to display at the end if it was successful. Each operation will result in a call to a WebAPI. (I do appreciate that it would be **much** better if the operations were passed in one call however this is not an option.

Unfortunately the number of calls is too many and it is effectively DOSing the API. I've tried to put in a pipe delay but maybe I'm not putting it in the correct place

```
const results: any[] = [];
this.bigArray.forEach(item =>
  results.push(
    this.aServiceWhichWillCallAPostMethod.doAnUpdate(item)
  )
);

forkJoin(results).subscribe(
  data => {
    Console.log('Yeah');
  },
  error => {
    Console.log('Oops');
  },
  () => {
  }
);
```

I've tried adding a delay here

```
this.aServiceWhichWillCallAPostMethod.doAnUpdate(item).pipe(delay(5000))
```

and here

```
forkJoin(results).subscribe
```

but with no luck

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961190/how-to-delay-forkjoin

Comment: I saw that post and as you can see i tried to use the pipe.delay

Comment: Do you want to wait for the previous observable to resolve before making the next call?

Comment: I don't need to but if it stops the DOS then it might be a way around the problem

Comment: Then rather use concatMap. concatMap does not need an array of observables, and it also uses the “Concat” Strategy — (Queuing up every new Observable, and subscribing to a new observable only when the last observable completed.)

Comment: I can post the code in the answer if the above explanation suits you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to try to rewrite your code to use mergeMap instead of forkJoin. [`.mergeMap()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) has native support to limit the concurrency at which your observables are invoked.

```
Rx.Observable.from(this.bigArray).mergeMap(
  item => this.aServiceWhichWillCallAPostMethod.doAnUpdate(item), */ project */
  undefined, /* resultselector */
  5 /* concurrency */
)
.subscribe();
```

This way you will have at max 5 items be processed (not order preserving, `merge` strategy).

Comment: Ha! I was trying to make that by hand here https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-mkujn3 I completely forgot about the concurrency, that's brilliant!