# How to receive multiple requests with Express.JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, express, nginx

I'm writing an Angular 6 + Express.JS app and now I stuck with the following problem: when there are some multiple requests made at the same time, sometimes (especially when there are more than 4 requests) all of them response with 404 or even get cancelled. Is there any problem with the way I handle requests in Express or I should add some tweaks for concurrent requests?

Requests:

```
let requests = [];
files.forEach((file) => {
    if (file.type.toLowerCase().includes('zip')) {
        requests.push(this.imagesService.uploadArchive(file).pipe(first()));
    } else {
        requests.push(this.imagesService.saveImage(file).pipe(first()));
    }
});

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(
    (res) => res.forEach(response => {
        this.onSave.emit(response);
    }), 
    (error) => {
        console.error(error);
    }, 
    () => {
        this.close.emit();
    }
);
```

Express handling routes:

```
router.post('/images',
    formidable({
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        uploadDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'uploads'),
        multiples: true,
        keepExtensions: true
    }),
    (req, res, next) => {
        const image = req.fields;
        const data = req.files;
        image.path = data.image.path;

        const file = fs.createReadStream(image.path);

        saveImage(image).then(
            result => {
                if (result) {
                    res.status(200).send(result);
                } else {
                    console.error("Cannot save image");
                    res.status(400).send("Cannot save image");
                }
        }).catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
});
```

Responses:
[image: responses.png]

## UPDATE

```
router.post('/archives',
    formidable({
        encoding: 'utf-8',
        uploadDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'uploads'),
        multiples: true,
        keepExtensions: true
    }),
    (req, res, next) => {
        const data = req.files;

        let promises = [];

        fs.readFile(data.archive.path, async (err, archive) => {
            if (err) throw err;

            await extractImagesFromZip(archive, data.archive.path).then((images) =>
                images.forEach((image) => {
                    promises.push(
                        saveImage(image).then(
                            result => {
                                if (result) {
                                    result.path = result.path.split('/').pop();
                                    return result;
                                } else {
                                    console.error("Cannot save image " + image.name);
                                    fs.unlink(image.path, () => {});
                                }
                        }).catch(e => {
                            fs.unlink(image.path, () => {});
                            console.error(e.stack)
                        })
                    );
                })
            );

            Promise.all(promises)
            .then((result) => {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    res.status(200).send(result)
                } else {
                    res.status(400).send("None images were saved")
                }
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.stack);
                res.status(400).send("None images were saved")
            });
        });
    }
);

export const extractImagesFromZip = (file, link) => {
    let promises = [];

    var zip = new JSZip();
    return zip.loadAsync(file)
    .then((archive) => {
        Object.values(archive.files).filter(
            f => 
                ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'].some((suffix) => f.name.toLowerCase().endsWith(suffix))
                && ![...f.name.toLowerCase().split('/')].pop().startsWith('.')
                && !f.dir 
        ).forEach(f => promises.push(zip.file(f.name).async('nodebuffer').then((content) => {
            const ext = f.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
            var dest = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..') + '/uploads/upload_'
                + crypto.randomBytes(Math.ceil(1322)).toString('hex').slice(0, 32).toLowerCase() 
                + '.' + ext;

            return new Promise((res, rej) => { 
                fs.writeFile(dest, content, (err) => { 
                    if (err) rej(err); 

                    res(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        fs.readFile(dest, (erro, data) => {
                            if (erro) reject(erro);
                            if (data) resolve({ 
                                name: f.name, 
                                type: 'image/' + (ext === 'jpg' ? 'jpeg' : ext), 
                                path: dest 
                            });
                        });
                    }));
                });
            });
        })));

        fs.unlink(link, () => {});

        return Promise.all(promises);
    });
}

export const saveImage = (image) => {
    return database.raw(
        "INSERT INTO images (name, type, path) " +
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?) " +
        "RETURNING name, type, path, id",
        [image.name, image.type, image.path]
    ).then(data => data.rows[0]).catch(e => console.error(e.stack));
};
```

## UPDATE 2

Everything works fine if user and server are on `localhost` (regardless server running with `nginx` or without it), but problem appears when server is remote

Comment: Where your saveImage api? are you requesting same method different parameter into one api method?

Comment: Here is the good architecture of express js just see and try to build your project look like this. https://github.com/mdshohelrana/mean-stack/tree/master/server

Comment: @Shohel I updated the question, pls, check it. Regarding architecture: mostly my app looks like this, yes. Any single request works well, but when I try to make some of them at once, I get stuck with this problem

Comment: @Shohel the main problem is that I can't understand what's going wrong. Logging shows no errors at all and I don't know where should I start to look for solution. None of guides I found specify work with multiple requests at once (I guess, that shouldn't be a problem) and haven't found any examples of the same problem I have

Comment: OK, bro, I am trying to find something. I will notify If I get.

Comment: @Shohel thx a lot! Can you, please, also check my duplicate of question on reddit? There is one guy helped me a little and I have an idea that maybe there is a problem with nginx https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/aqil9u/how_to_receive_multiple_requests/eggkrf5/

Comment: Could you try to delay into forkjoin? just see the example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961190/how-to-delay-forkjoin

Comment: @Shohel, hello again. I tried it and nothing changed. But everything works fine if I run server on localhost. If I run it with nginx on remote server, that's when problem starts. Is this connected to nginx configuration anyhow? If I get it right, there shouldn't be problem.

Comment: Sorry bro, I do not know the configuration of nginx. Now I will study now about nginx

Comment: @Shohel it was just an idea tho. What was the point of delay?

Comment: Yes bro, Some people are saying use delay or async and await

Comment: Bro, would you like to share the log of nginx from /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: @Shohel https://pastebin.com/1zn4T1q2

Comment: Bro, why 127.0.0.1 or localhost to your remote server?

Comment: @Shohel nginx serves port 4200, backend script runs on 9901 and I use proxy, so request `hostname:4200/api/archives` changes to `localhost:9901/archives` by nginx (`localhost` is the same as `hostname`)

Comment: @Shohel I double checked it and there is nothing wrong with `nginx`. I tried to run run nginx on localhost and everything's fine again... I'm just running out of ideas what can possibly be wrong

Comment: Bro, I am very sorry, I could not help you. Without an actual project, it is very hard to identify what is going on to you. Ok. let me study again about nginx. Thanks.

Comment: @Shohel no problem. And thanks again fr your help. At least, I decreased the number of possible causes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such code worked

```
public async uploadFiles(files: File[]) {
    of(files)
        .pipe(
            concatMap(files =>
                files.map(file => {
                    return this.imagesService
                        .saveImage(file)
                        .pipe(
                            map(),
                            catchError((error, caught) => {
                                console.error(error);

                                return empty();
                            })
                        );
                })
            ),
            concatAll(),
            toArray(),
            map(res => console.log)
        )
        .subscribe();
}
```